# Use Quickblox.framework in Swift application

Tags: xcode, swift, quickblox

I'm trying to connect [QuickBlox.framework](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework) to the Swift application.

As I know QuickBlox.framework is written on Objective-C.
To use it in Swift application we should follow [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html)

What I did is:

1. Create bridge header **demo-swift-Bridging-Header.h**
2. Import QuickBlox here: `#import <Quickblox/Quickblox.h>`

and I got 28 errors:

```
<unknown>:0: error: ./Quickblox.framework/Headers/Core/Definitions/Consts.h:16: unknown type name 'NSString'
...
<unknown>:0: error: ./Quickblox.framework/Headers/Core/Definitions/Delegates.h:43: expected a type
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify a bit your bridge file - add all needed frameworks

```
@import Foundation
@import SystemConfiguration;
@import MobileCoreServices;

#import <Quickblox/Quickblox.h>
```

Checkout QuickBlox blog post about Swift http://quickblox.com/blog/2014/06/building-ios-apps-with-quickblox-and-swift/

Comment: Hi, does this ensure all other chat functionalities can be implemented in QuickBlox using swift ?